# Python - How to slice with multi indexes and conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a multi dataframe with `id` and `month` as indexes

[image]

For each `id` (index 1), I want to be able to slice `month` (index 2) up until the last non-zero value in columns amount1 or amount2.

Desired output
[image]

I've tried slicing all ids but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to slice different chucks for each ids:

```
df.loc[:,:max(df[df['amount1'] != 0].index)[1]]
```

Comment: Can you please share the output expected for the above example? Also it would be good to have any code attempt you may have.

Comment: @Cedric updated question

Comment: Are you sure the output is the one you posted? I believe there are two rows missing. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more efficient option. But with below code you can achieve what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

# We create the original dataframe
arrays = [[102,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,103,103,103,103,103,103,103,104,104,104,104,104,104,104,104,104,104],
["11/1/2004","12/1/2004","1/1/2005","2/1/2005","3/1/2005","4/1/2005","5/1/2005","6/1/2005","4/1/2003","5/1/2003","6/1/2003","7/1/2003","8/1/2003","9/1/2003","10/1/2003","8/1/2003","9/1/2003","10/1/2003","11/1/2003","12/1/2003","1/1/2004","2/1/2004","3/1/2004","4/1/2004","5/1/2004"]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['id', 'month'])
amount1 = [0,0,-9100000,0,1444.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5.4e7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3.3e7,-4.3e7,0,0,0,0]
amount2 = [1105.900001,0,1037.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,117.4199962,117.315,0,0,107.77771641,105.9499986,0,106.3398808,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({"amount1": amount1, "amount2": amount2},index=index)

# We slice the dataframe by ids
df_out_list = list()
for i,id in enumerate(df.index.levels[0]):
    df2 = df.xs((id,))
    df2_nonzeros = df2[(df2['amount1'] != 0) | (df2['amount2'] != 0)]
    df2_result = df2[:df2_nonzeros.tail(1).index[0]]
    N = len(df2_result.index)
    arrays = [[id]*N, df2_result.index]
    tuples_result = list(zip(*arrays))
    index_result = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_result, names=['id', 'month'])
    df_out_list.append(pd.DataFrame({"amount1": list(df2_result["amount1"]),"amount2": list(df2_result["amount2"])},index=index_result))

# We create the output dataframe appending the dataframes by id
for i,df_el in enumerate(df_out_list):
    if i==0:
        df_out = df_el
    else:
        df_out = df_out.append(df_el)

print df
print df_out
```

Output for such is:

[image]